# Getting different version error while opening mdf file from website in visual studio 2015

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

While opening solution of other developer.
Error received is:
     **'28-10-2015\28-10-2015\BLUE_EYE\APP_DATA\BLUEEYENEW.MDF' cannot be opened because it is version 835. This server supports version 782 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported'**

Also tried solution mentioned in other posts for checking data connection in option tab of visual studio but didn't worked .Earlier same solution was working and could open mdf file as well.But suddenly stopped working.Thanks for help.